# SSAS Tabular: How to fix "Failed to connect to the server. Reason: SSL Security Error" while trying to open an existing model on server

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, ssas-2017

After some long time passed since a SSAS Tabular model development and deployment I found myself unable to refresh the model (see screenshot below) furthermore I didn't change a thing in this model (and infrastructure was also the same) since the development time.

The error I got from the Tabular Model Designer

> Failed to connect to the server. Reason: [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen
>   (SECCreateCredentials()).]SSL Security error.

[image: x]

How to fix or get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found was to change a provider (Menu -> Extensions -> Model -> Existing Connections -> Edit -> Build -> Advanced) from SQLOLEDB to SQLNCLIxx (from OLEDB to SQL Native Client)

[image]